# Spring-boot: RestControllerAdvise not reached

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've built a `RestControlerAdvise`:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler({DocumentAlreadyExistsException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error handleException(DocumentAlreadyExistsException e) {

        cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error error = new cat.gencat.ctti.canigo.arch.web.rs.model.Error();
        error.setCode(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        error.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        return error;

    }

}
```

Nevertheless, it's never reached even though I raise an `DocumentAlreadyExistException`.

It's detected on boot:

> 2018-08-20 17:08:25.791  INFO 4941 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in exceptionControllerAdvice

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment(consider it as a comment). Can you post snippets of your @Controller class, you may be handling the DocumentAlreadyExistException instead of throwing it out for spring to handle it ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. I tested it in my project and this code was executed. Do you catch it somewhere in your code? For example with ``try{...}catch(Exception e){...}``?

Comment: As @jay mentioned, please show one or more controller methods that throw the DocumentAlreadyExistsException. Note, you say you raise DocumentAlreadyExistException but the advice is looking for DocumentAlreadyExistsException.

Answer (score 6):

I ran the same code in my application and its working fine, also please note

> @ExceptionHandler methods on the Controller are always selected before
>   those on any @ControllerAdvice instance. It is undefined what order
>   controller-advices are processed.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomExceptionHandler  {

    @ExceptionHandler(value={Exception.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public final ErrorMessage exceptionHandler(Exception e)
    {
        ErrorMessage msg=new ErrorMessage();
        msg.setError("its an error");

        return msg;
    }
```

also please refer the following link for more information : 
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

You may be handling the DocumentAlreadyExistException instead of throwing it out for spring to handle it.

Comment: my earlier accepted answer was deleted by administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Exception handler class is in the same package or inside the package where the controller exists.

For example:
If the package where the controller is found is:

```
package com.test.component.controller;
```

Then use the same package for the handler or use this:

```
package com.test.component.controller.exceptionhandler;
```